# Gradle sync failed on new Empty Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This is my first time trying to use Android studios. I downloaded the latest version of Android Studio Arctic Fox. Created a new project with an Empty Activity immediately returns a `Gradle Sync started`.

```
4:19 PM Gradle sync started

4:19 PM Gradle sync failed: Cause: invalid code -- missing end-of-block (618 ms)
```

Note that I did not change anything of the default code in the `MainActivity.kt`

package com.example.firstapptest

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

As per other SO questions I have tried to remove the cache. I do not know how to debug this or continue.

*Edit:*

The `build.gradle` file in the top directory

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the `build.gradle` file inside the app folder:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firstapptest"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

The `gradlew build --stacktrace` is more then 3 times too long for the character limit and as such [I have used pastebin:](https://pastebin.com/A330MHt2)

The contents of `settings.gradle`:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
rootProject.name = "First App Test"
include ':app'
```

[See this github repo for all the files.](https://github.com/mjpvz/androidEmptyApp)

Comment: the issue could be in your `build.gradle` files. can you post them here? one can be found in the root of your project directory and the other is in the `app` folder within the project directory.

Comment: Now added to the main body of the question.

Comment: Gradle scrips look fine. Try running `./gradlew build --debug --stacktrace` in studio terminal to see whether you can get a detailed error.

Comment: Added the stacktrace to the main body. It exceeded the character limit and as such a small portion has been removed that seemed insignificant. The `Java home is different.` portion might be of interest?

Comment: Oh. Remove `--debug` and try `./gradlew build --stacktrace`. And add `[Gradle]` tag to the question as well

Comment: I have replaced the stacktrace now without the `--debug` flag.

Comment: It says, the problem is in your `settings.gradle`, post it here.

Comment: @Praveen I have included it.

Comment: Take a backup of `settings.gradle` then remove all lines in it except for the `include ':app'`  then try again.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala The error does not change when all lines except `include ':app'` are removed

Comment: Can u upload ur project to Github?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala I have included it at the bottom now.